# How to get a subset from BatchDataSet or PrefetchDataset in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

For example:

```
raw_train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory(
    '../ml-test-data/aclImdb/train',
    batch_size=batch_size,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset='training',
    seed=seed)

train_ds = raw_train_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
```

`raw_train_ds` is a BatchDataSet and `train_ds` is a PrefetchDataSet of 625 batches. How can I get a subset of either `BatchDataSet` or `PrefetchDataSet`, for example, only the first 10 batches, or the first 320 examples?

If I convert them into a list, the problem is that later code is using the PrefetchDataSet type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get samples by `take()` function. It returns an iterable object. So you can get items like this:

```
ds_subset = raw_train_ds.take(10) #returns first 10 batch, if the data has batched

for data_batch in ds_subset:
    #do whatever you want with each batch
```

or if you want to get examples, not batches:

```
ds_subset = raw_train_ds.unbatch().take(320) #returns first 320 examples

for input, label in ds_subset:
   #do whatever you want with each sample (input,label)
```